# How to store/output dlls of a separately created project in Sitecore Helix compliant solution?

Tags: helix

I am using Sitecore 8.1 update 3.

Due to conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly , I want to create a separate project in same Sitecore Helix compliant solution.

I am anticipating if I don't include new project in Feature/Project/Foundation Layer and create it under a 4th Folder then the dlls of that project should not be pushed to Webroot/website/bin folder.

I am using gulp.config file which publishes dlls, views, other files to webroot in its defined task list.

[image]

Now , for example , consider new project requires Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 10.0.0 and other projects in Feature/Project/Foundation require Newtonsoft.json 6.0.0 , hence my requirement is to output this Newtonsoft.json version 10.0.0 in another folder in Webroot/Website other than Webroot/website/bin folder.

The new project does not need to have any of the Sitecore's dll in reference , it needs to have Twilio's reference which has dependency on other assemblies which is creating version conflict with dlls versions of projects under Feature/Project/Foundation.

Is there any way to do this ? or Sitecore Projects dlls should always be in bin folder only ?

Comment: You can right click on dll in visual studio and go to properties and make CopyLocal to false, then it will not deploy

Comment: What are your plans deploying this? If it should not be part of your solution due to different version dependencies then create another solution and have it there but still the question is about deployment this. Which project will reference this Twilio project?

Comment: @Gaurav, I am not asking about how to make sure dll is not copied, my requirement is about copying dll in another folder

Comment: @Peter , yes if another solution is created or a WEB API project is an alternative . 

But I am trying to see if it is possible in same solution with creation of Twilio project. 

The problem occurs when I try to publish the Source code using Gulp task it does not copy the dll of Twilio project because Twilio dll installed from Nuget has dependency of latest version of a dll and other projects on Feature/Foundation layer has dependency on dll by same name but of older version.

Comment: So basically , I want to publish Twilio project which is not in Feature/Foundation/Project layer in another folder than bin so that there is no conflict problem of dll versions with same name, hope you have understood what my pain is here :)